# Vuetify active class not applied when Color attribute is set

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have some issues applying an active class to the selected V-Card element when a Color Attribute is set:

Example:

```js
<v-col v-for="data in datas" :key="data.id">
<v-card
  style="height: 10vh;"
  flat
  dark
  color="green" // <--- When set my selectedItem Class is not applied
  @click="doSomething(), activeId=data.id"
  :class="{ 'selectedItem' : activeId === data.id}"
>
{{ data.id }}
</v-card>
```

```css
<style scoped>
.selectedItem {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
</style>
```

When the color attribute is not applied and the background is white the selectedItem Class is working fine!

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the color attribute in Vuetify you're applying the background-color in CSS with a higher level of specificity than your class that's being applied. You can check your inspector output to see this behavior.

Because color will apply its style with `.v-application` as the parent selector. If you want to compete with this in your stylesheet you can do this:

```css
.v-application .selectedItem {
 background: blue !important
}
```